# socket.io-php: "missing script: start" at install.json

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

I want to create a .io game with supports some PHP apis, and I tried to execute this files:

## install.json:

```
{
    "name"  : "workerman/phpsocket.io",
    "type"  : "library",
    "keywords": ["socket.io"],
    "homepage": "http://www.workerman.net",
    "license" : "MIT",
    "require": {
        "workerman/workerman" : ">=3.5.16",
        "workerman/channel" : ">=1.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"PHPSocketIO\\": "./src"}
    }
}
```

## start.php

```
use Workerman\Worker;
use PHPSocketIO\SocketIO;
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Listen port 2021 for socket.io client
$io = new SocketIO(2021);
$io->on('connection', function ($socket) use ($io) {
    $socket->on('chat message', function ($msg) use ($io) {
        $io->emit('chat message', $msg);
    });
});

Worker::runAll();
```

And it gave me this error at doing command `npm start`:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-01T14_16_55_432Z-debug.log
```

What could I do for solving this error and execute this package sucesfully???

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to provide the script you want to run. In your case, `install.js`?

```
{
    "name"  : "workerman/phpsocket.io",
    "type"  : "library",
    "keywords": ["socket.io"],
    "homepage": "http://www.workerman.net",
    "license" : "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "npm run install.js"
    },
    "require": {
        "workerman/workerman" : ">=3.5.16",
        "workerman/channel" : ">=1.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"PHPSocketIO\\": "./src"}
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I have tried to do that and it gives me the same error :'v
(And also doing "npm run start.php") :'v

Comment: Do you have a node script in the project? and do you have a package.json file?

Comment: When you are writing `npm run start`, what that means is that npm will check your package.json file and look for the scripts key and run the command you passed. in your case `start`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know the command for start a php file as serverfile.

Comment: I don't think you can run a php file via node/npm.

Comment: I dont think also, but I followed this example: https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io

Comment: Oh, you have to write `php start.php start`, as said in the example :D